# Launch EC2: The requested configuration is currently not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

The below is the command

```sh
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-0f90a34c9df977efb --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name clikey --security-group-ids sg-0b018f6a888e80890 --subnet-id subnet-4d0a2273 --region=us-east-1
```

Here is the error message:

> An error occurred (Unsupported) when calling the RunInstances operation: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

Need your suggestion to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The User is given admin access, the key with same name is created.

Comment: Can you double check that your security group is in the same VPC as the Subnet you specify? Perhaps the AMI you're choosing doesn't support a t2.micro instance type? There is some sort of combination here that isn't supported, and unfortunately the error isn't too helpful

Comment: Thanks mate, issue resolve. Tried with different AMI. Still dont know why I was not able to create instance with previous AMI

Comment: Can you let me know how to get AMI Id's using CLI command?

Comment: You should post a separate question to get AMI ID using cli.
You can find the answer here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html

You'll have to use "--filters"